# App Engine + HTTPS + PageSpeed = 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, python-2.7, https

The application is on Google App Engine (Python 2.7, webapp2, HighReplication) working properly with HTTPS.

The HTTPS is configured in the app.yaml with the secure: always attribute, instead schemes=['https'] in routes.

so far everything OK, If I do a "curl -I **HTTP**://[MY_URL]" , the answer is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: HTTPS://[MY_URL]
```

This 302 is OK, because means the resources has another location (with HTTPS)

But.... when I enable **PageSpeed** on "App Engine -> Application Settings", I have this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

I know what 403 error is, but why does it happens only when I enable PageSpeed and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have not refered the FAQ of google please refer this [`link`](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/faq)
this says you need to provide,

1. You sign up and provide us with your serving and origin servers.
2. You send traffic to PageSpeed Service by pointing your DNS CNAME entry to pagespeed.googlehosted.com.

Also Python needs to be configured for page speed, refer link [`PAGESPEED`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#pagespeed)

and its still experimental

and refer this [`link`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings)
Find this point "Enabling PageSpeed Optimization Service"

this link says its paid service you need to pay per GB bandwidth, it optimizes your pages automatically!!!

I hope you will work around the problem after this reading links.

If you are not novice user, you do not required this if you are not adding any useless thing to your app's pages.